# How to set close browser or tab when open pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to set show alert when close browser or tab.
I tried use of javascript and jquery but my problem is not solved yet.
Please tell me if you have any script for only close browser or tab when open alert.
But not show alert in refresh page it iss display alert only close browser or tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
     alert("!");
   }
```

**Note :** But this will also show when you refresh your page, because when a page is refresh and unload the DOM, the `onbeforeunload` event will always be called.